# Is there a way to use default Word or PDF images/icons as the thumbnail rather than generic greyed out background?

Tags: javascript, css, dropzone.js

I want to change the generic greyed out background for word/pdf files in dropzone file preview. This is the default view:

[image]

Which is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is the way I did it finally:

```
myAwesomeDropzone.on('addedfile', function(file) {

    var ext = file.name.split('.').pop();

    if (ext == "pdf") {
        $(file.previewElement).find(".dz-image img").attr("src", "/Content/Images/pdf.png");
    } else if (ext.indexOf("doc") != -1) {
        $(file.previewElement).find(".dz-image img").attr("src", "/Content/Images/word.png");
    } else if (ext.indexOf("xls") != -1) {
        $(file.previewElement).find(".dz-image img").attr("src", "/Content/Images/excel.png");
    }
});
```

The images must be 120x120 pixels to fit the default preview template.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. Any reason why you're using `(ext.indexOf("pdf") != -1)` instead of `(ext == "pdf")`?

Comment: Not really, and makes no sense for .pdf actually!. I did it in that way for the other formats because a word document can be .doc/.docx and excel .xls/.xlsx/.xlsm. I've already edited the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Are these icons free to use? What are the copyright restrictions?

Comment: If you already included FontAwesome on your website, you can use `$(file.previewElement).find(".dz-image img").replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>');` and others.

Answer (score 21):

I found a simple way to do this just now. Please note that I **am** using jQuery, so make sure to include that, too.

First of all, make sure your Dropzone has an `id`. Mine is `myAwesomeDropzone`:

```
<form id="myAwesomeDropzone" action="/upload-target" class="dropzone"></form>
```

Second, create image icons for each filetype you want to include. I found icons for PDF and Word and put them in a directory called `img`.

Then include the following JavaScript:

```
// Make sure to use YOUR Dropzone's ID below...
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  accept: function(file, done) {
    var thumbnail = $('.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview .dz-image:last');

    switch (file.type) {
      case 'application/pdf':
        thumbnail.css('background', 'url(img/pdf.png');
        break;
      case 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document':
        thumbnail.css('background', 'url(img/doc.png');
        break;
    }

    done();
  },
};
```

The code above will work for PDF and Word. If you want to add more, just add more `case`s to the `switch` statement using this template:

```
case '[mime type]':
  thumbnail.css('background', 'url(img/[icon filename]');
  break;
```

Note that you can find the mime type by adding `console.log(file.type);` in the `accept` function, then drop a test file and check your browser's console.

### Explanation

Dropzone allows you to configure a dropzone with a configuration object in the form of `Dropzone.options.[your dropzone's id]`. One of the options is an `accept` function that is fired before a file is accepted. You can use this function's first parameter to spy on the incoming file.

That parameter has properties such as `type` which can tell you the mime type. Once you know the mime type, you can change the element's background image using CSS. Our element will always be `$('.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview .dz-image:last')` since we always want to target the latest dropzone file. Just change the background-image to an appropriate icon. For example, any of [these](http://findicons.com/search/pdf) will work for PDF.

Comment: I prefer this solution because of checking mime type, not file extension which can be simply invalid.

Comment: I like this approach. I noticed in edge cases adjacent thumbnails were being modified instead of the target. I found: `var thumbnail = $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-image:last');` was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
this.emit("thumbnail", file, "/WebResources/cre_pdf_icon");
```

or

```
myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", file, "/WebResources/cre_pdf_icon");
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a variation of the answer given by @Gabriel

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone= {
            init: function () {
                this.on("addedfile", function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    var ext = data.name.split('.').pop();

                    if (ext == "pdf") {
                        $(data.previewElement).find(".dz-image img").attr("src", "/Content/Images/pdf.png");
                    } else if (ext.indexOf("doc") != -1) {
                        $(data.previewElement).find(".dz-image img").attr("src", "/Content/Images/word.png");
                    } else if (ext.indexOf("xls") != -1) {
                        $(data.previewElement).find(".dz-image img").attr("src", "/Content/Images/excel.png");
                    } else if (ext.indexOf("xlsx") != -1) {
                        $(data.previewElement).find(".dz-image img").attr("src", "/Content/Images/excel.png");
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, it's important to resize thumbnail image, so you should add a line to resize.

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzoneUpload = {
    accept: function(file, done) {

        switch (file.type) {
          case 'application/pdf':
              this.emit("thumbnail", file, "/static/img/pdf.png");            
              break;
          case 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document':
              this.emit("thumbnail", file, "/static/img/word.png"); 
              break;
        }
        file.previewTemplate.querySelector(".dz-image img").style.width="120px";

        done();
    }
};
```